# Regex to find multiple occurrences of the same character with excluding words in line

Tags: regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio 2017 Search (uses .NET Framework regular expressions) trying to build a complex regex and i didn't manage to combine them together.

The regex will search each line for multiple occurrences of the character =.The target should be between two =. 
But i want to exclude multiple words like (AND, OR, SELECT etc)

My query for now look like this :

```
^(=.*){2}.$
```

Desired results:

> Match () A (= B =) C
>
> Match () A AND A (= B =) C)

X Avoid  A = D AND B = C

X Avoid A == B

Comment: Try `=(?:(?!\b(?:AND|OR|SELECT)\b)[^=])+=`

Comment: I am not sure how to test for my specific regex engine either.

Comment: The input is my huge code base, where i am trying to find all bugs using the regex search of visual studio.

Comment: http://regexstorm.net/tester for .NET

Comment: VS S&R regex is a tiny bit different from a common .NET regex. The S&R feature is also a bit buggy when it comes to replacement.

Comment: Upon running it from VS i got incorrect results. Using the Supercharger's superfinder plugin i got the correct. @WiktorStribiżew , please answer the question.

Comment: What is different in the results between the two tools?

Comment: I guess different engine. I was not able to find what regex engine the superfinder uses.

Comment: Yes, but why VS built-in did not work? What did SC find and VS S&R didn't?

Comment: Visual studio's results seem to return as a result the line Me._RedirectionType = value which is incorrect. SC found only lines with multiple = present.

Comment: Just pasted `Me._RedirectionType = value` into VS2017 and my pattern does not find any match on that line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183299/discussion-between-vfle-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
=(?:(?!\b(?:AND|OR|SELECT)\b)[^=])+=
```

Note that in VS search and replace tool, the `[^=]`, a negated character class, does not match line breaks. If you want to make sure it does not match line breaks add `\r` and `\n` inside, `[^=\r\n]`.

**Details**

- `=` - a `=` symbol
- `(?:(?!\b(?:AND|OR|SELECT)\b)[^=])+` - any char but `=` (`[^=]`), 1 or more repetitions (`+`), that does not start any of the substrings inside the non-capturing group (`AND`, `OR` or `SELECT`) as whole words (since `\b` matches a word boundary)
- `=` - a `=` symbol

[image]